# Type Cast: Map[String,String] to Map[String,Object]

Tags: java, scala, sbt, scala-collections

I am new to scala and when I compile my SBT project, I see this exception:

```
[error] C:\dev\reactive-rabbit\src\main\scala\io\scalac\amqp\impl\RabbitConnection.scala:58: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Map[String,String] (in scala.collection.immutable)
[error]  required: Map[String,Object] (in java.util)
[error]     future(onChannel(_.exchangeBind(destination, source, routingKey, arguments)))
[error]                                                                      ^
```

I recently replaced the deprecated `JavaConversions` library to `JavaConverters`. My Code looks like this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConvertors._
override def exchangeBind(destination: String, source: String, routingKey: String,
                        arguments: Map[String, String]) =
    future(onChannel(_.exchangeBind(destination, source, routingKey, arguments)))
      .map(_ ⇒ Exchange.BindOk())
```

I looked at the contract for `onChannel()` and its `arguments` parameter requires type `Map[String, Object]` (java collections) but I am passing it a Map[String, String] (scala immutable). How can I change the data type for this argument while passing it to the method? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Scala `Map` is covariant in value type parameter, so `Map[String, String]` is already `Map[String, Object]`, no `map` or `mapValues` necessary. You can assign it to a `val` with desired type or use type ascription: `arguments: Map[String, Object]`. Then call `asJava`:

```
(arguments: Map[String, Object]).asJava
```

Note that using `asInstanceOf` where not necessary, as the other answers do, is bad style: if you change the types later, the compiler can't tell you where your code needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaConverters instead of JavaConversions (it is deprecated) and also map String to Object to prevent the following error:

```
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.Map[String,String]
 required: java.util.Map[String,Object]
Note: String <: Object, but Java-defined trait Map is invariant in type V.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Object`. (SLS 3.2.10)
       javaMap = Map[String,String]().asJava
```

.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

var javaMap: java.util.Map[String,Object] = new java.util.HashMap()
javaMap.put("key", "value")

println(javaMap)

javaMap = Map[String,String]("new_key" -> "new_value").map{case (k,v) => (k, v.asInstanceOf[Object])}.asJava

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

{key=value}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
javaMap: java.util.Map[String,Object] = {new_key=new_value}
javaMap: java.util.Map[String,Object] = {new_key=new_value}

scala>
```

Comment: The conversion using `map` isn't actually necessary and will just take time and memory.